# Checking if Dict Value exists

Tags: python, maya

I tried searching for an answer but did not find anything that helps. So I have to ask.

I have a password collector which right now runs every time I run the script. The value is then stored in memory to use it for that session.

Even if I close that script as long as maya is still open, I can access the password.

What I need is a way to see if the value is already in the memory or not.
When I use

```
print argdict['password']
```

I can see that the dict is in my memory.
I tried to get something like

```
if argdict['password'] in locals():
    print 'its alive'
```

but that doesn't return anything, what would be the correct way to check if a dict key or value exists or not.

Comment: what is value of `argdict['password']` if your password is not loaded?

Answer (score 4):

Use this:
`if 'password' in argdict:`

Comment: this is the idiomatic way to check for a key. If you don't know if the key has a value, you can do pwd = argdict.get('password', None), which will return None if password is not present as @Fear3dlegend mentions

Answer (score 2):

To test if "password" is among the values of your dictionary.

```
 "password" in d.itervalues()
```

To test if "password" is among the keys of your dictionary.

```
 "password" in d.keys()
```

Comment: In Python 2.x *"password" in d.keys()* will create a redundant list. *"password" in d* works as well - and does not waste resources on list creation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `in`:

```
if 'password' in argdict:
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I think may be more elegant is:

```
if argsdict.get('password', False):
    # do whatever
```

It will try to see if `argsdict` has a 'password' key/value pair, but if not, it will resort to the default value, which I provided as `False.` Thus, the conditional becomes `if False` when there is not 'password' key, so the conditional block will not run.

However, this also will not execute if you have an object that is considered `False` as the value of 'password'. Various values that are evaluated as `False` (try `bool(some_object)` to see whether it is evaluated as True or False): `0, None, '', {}, []`, etc. Most empty containers are `False`.

Because of this, this is probably your best bet:

```
if 'password' in argsdict:
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to check if the dict exists is to simply use the name:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> 'd' in locals()
True
```

And to see if it's a dict:

```
>>> isinstance(d, dict)
True
```

To check for the key:

```
>>> d['password'] = 'foo'
>>> 'password' in d
True
```

To check that a value exists (and is non-empty):

```
>>> if d.get('password'): print True
...
True
```

To check if the value is a particular value:

```
>>> d.get('password') == 'foo'
True
```